# iPhone X Simulator not running my app in full screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9, iphone-x

Downloaded GM for Xcode 9, and tried running my app on the iPhone X-simulator. See image below (content omitted).

It's letterboxed! Black border over and under all view controllers. Why? Talked to someone else who had tried the same with their app, but it simply worked for them. I don't even know where to start looking. The app targets iOS8, so I can't turn on safe-areas in Storyboard (as far as I understand), but that shouldn't be causing this..
This app is from 2015 from the baby stages of Swift 1, but has been maintained all the way, and is now Swift 4. (Supported down to iOS7 in the beginning).

If I open my storyboard and choose "View as iPhone X" at the bottom it looks perfect, but it shows up letterboxed in simulator..

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You must provide a LaunchScreen for iPhone X. Do you use png launch screens in your project?

Comment: @diegotrevisan You got it right! I realised it right after posting this question. The phones will only launch in the same sizes as the assets. Want to post it as an answer?

Comment: @diegotrevisan It makes no sense to state that you need to provide a LaunchScreen for iPhone X. An app only has one LaunchScreen and the one LaunchScreen allows the app to work on all devices. If an app already uses a LaunchScreen then there is nothing to do for the iPhone X. If you actually meant "launch images" instead of LaunchScreen then that is something completely different. Either way, it's covered by the duplicate linked at the top of the question.

Comment: @rmaddy I think we all understood what diego meant by saying "Do you use **png** launch screens?"..

Comment: Yes I mixed up the names, using launch images is a very old technique.